# Beautiful Soup - Several Attributes searching

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, attributes, tags

With Beautiful Soup, I would like to find in a HTML code all the tags 'a' which have an attribute "class" equal to "button btn-1-small" OR an attribute "class" equal to "button beta-callout btn-1-small". My code is:

```
alltd = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'button btn-1-small'}, {'class':'button 
beta-callout btn-1-small'})
```

My code works perfectly when I have only one condition (one value for "class"), but when I want to have two conditions, it doesn't work anymore.

Would you know how to write a condition "OR" ? In order to have either a value for the class either the other one

Thank you very much.

Lcs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, `'button btn-1-small'` has *multiple* classes, which mean just doing `soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'btn-1-small'})` would return both elements.

However, to find elements with one class or the other, you'd pass a list instead.

So if you have HTML as:

```
<a href="#" class="foo">Test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="bar">Test 2</a>
```

You can select either one with:

```
soup.find_all('a', {'class': ['foo', 'bar']})
```

Comment: The solution with the list works perfectly, thank you very much.